# Sorting in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a string "abc" and I am greping it in 15 files in my directory in shell.
When I `grep "abc"` in my 15 files than it returns me the whole line of the files in which its present like this:

```
abc 0.2  9.0
abc 0.01 8.0
abc 0.06 9.4
abc 0.02 8.7
```

Now I want this output to be sorted in ascending order according to the second column.

So I wrote the command like this:

```
grep "abc" *.txt | sort -nr -t_ -k2
```

but the above command is not working and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: you've used `-t_` to specify the field separator, but the output doesn't contain `_` characters.

Next problem: the `-k` option has two arguments, start field and end field. By omitting the end field, you get end_of_line by default.

I'd suggest writing it like this:

```
grep "abc" *.txt | sort -nr -k2,2
```

Comment: You can use `-k2` as a shorthand for `-k2,2`.  The man page says: _ `-k`, `--key=POS1[,POS2]`
              start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)_.

Comment: That's not correct, sorry. Quoting the full coreutils manual, -k means "Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted)".

Comment: And you are going to spot the difference...how?

Comment: Because it changes the sort key to span multiple fields in ways you probably didn't intend. Please see the comments to example `sort -t : -k 2,2n -k 5.3,5.4` here: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#sort-invocation

Answer (score 3):

Your command is not working because you don't have underscores separating the columns; further, you wanted the data ascending but you told it to sort in reverse (descending) order.  Use:

```
grep "abc" *.txt | sort -n -k 2
```

Or:

```
grep "abc" *.txt | sort -k 2n
```

Note that if there are multiple files, your `grep` output will be prefixed with a file name.  You will have to decide whether that matters.  It only screws things up if there are spaces in any of the file names.  The `-h` option to `grep` suppresses the file names.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to delete `-t_` parameter, because as I see you use spaces as separator, not underscore. After that it works for me:

```
$ cat t | sort -n -k2
abc 0.01 8.0
abc 0.02 8.7
abc 0.06 9.4
abc 0.2  9.0
```

**Updated:** and yes, as @jonathan-leffler said you also should omit `-r` option for sorting in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your entire script, including the call to `grep`, with one call to `awk`

```
awk '/abc/{a[$2,i++]=$0}END{l=asorti(a,b);for(i=1;i<=l;i++)print a[b[i]]}' *.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ ls *.txt
four.txt  one.txt  three.txt  two.txt

$ cat *.txt
abc 0.02 8.3
foo
abc 0.06 9.4
bar
blah blah
abc 0.2  9.0
blah
abc 0.01 8.0
blah
abc 0.02 8.7
blah blah

$ awk '/abc/{a[$2,i++]=$0}END{l=asorti(a,b);for(i=1;i<=l;i++)print a[b[i]]}' *.txt
abc 0.01 8.0
abc 0.02 8.3
abc 0.02 8.7
abc 0.06 9.4
abc 0.2  9.0
```

Comment: (1) `asorti()` is a GNU `awk` extension; since the question is tagged Linux, this is not a major issue.  (2) The assignment `a[$2] = $0` means that you are only saving unique values from the second column, not all lines that match.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Good catch on the `a[$2]`, fixed.